# call another function from another JS file?

Tags: javascript, function, file

In file second.js, I want to call a function A from first.js ? How to import ?
I tried to import like import a module( export function in first.js) but it didnt work. Thanks

Comment: Please edit this question to include what you tried.

Comment: Can you please more specific about your case and do provide some code part ?

Comment: Please share your code so we know how to debug it

Comment: I found your answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: I found your answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a browser environment then you should include the scripts with the attribute type = "module"

Eg.

```
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
```